# How can i delete a file.txt sent by Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this [Tasklist](http://dev.alurosu.com/bobo/Task/tasklist.php) ,everytime you type something and press ADD ,Ajax is sending the data to **ajax.php**

*This is ajax.php code*

```
       <?php

       $my_file = "../data/Tasklist/" . $_POST['task'] . ".txt";
       $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w');

       $data = $_POST["task"] .";" . $_POST["date"] .";". $_POST["text"];
       fwrite($handle, $data);
        ?>
```

What i want to do is , when i press Delete a new Ajax is sending the data(.txt) to a new file called remove.php.

In remove.php i must write a fread and unlink function i quess so it can be deleted.

Sorry if i didn't explained that good.

Can anyone tell me how ?
Thank You very much.

**JS:**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Del").click(function(event){
$.post( "data/remove.php",{id:"'. $file . '" }) 

  .done(function(id){

      })
```

**remove.php**

```
$file = fopen('/data/Tasklist/);
fread($file);
fclose($file);

unlink($file);
```

Comment: unlink wants a filename, not a file descriptor.

Comment: Can you show how you display the files. Show us some HTML.

Comment: [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)? What manual?

Comment: ive uploaded the code (http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/1767)

Comment: Some of the code on your site is vulnerable to XSS. Check this for example ;-) http://dev.alurosu.com/bobo/problema%206/editor.php

Comment: how u got that i didnt post it here :/ + it brings me here on forum..

Comment: @zan yea because I put into the text field `<script>window.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com/#...';</script>`. You have directory listing activated on your server = shows all folder contents where there is no index file.

Comment: Nvm anyway .thats not the problem i want to fix :D

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the filename from your button id and send it to $.post,

```
 var filename=encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('id'));
```

i.e as you are using the class $(".Del") you can use $(this) inside the click event other wise just use the class selector $(".Del")

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".Del").click(function(event){
           var filename=encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('id'));
           $.post( "data/remove.php",{id:filename });
    });
});
```

In `remove.php` get the file name,

```
$filename='/data/Tasklist/'.$_POST['id']; // $filename='/data/Tasklist/TESTTTT.txt'

unlink($filename);
```

Comment: Check this (http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/1767) i uploaded all the code , what i want to do is delete the file that was pressed on the button Delete